# React Hooks: How to clean event listeners?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, addeventlistener, use-effect

I have a component `Example` in which I want to clear **event listener** when the local state  `display` changes to **false**,`display` is set to **true** when `show` prop is **true** and vice versa.

**Code:**

```
const Example = ({ show, onClose }) => {
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    onClose();
    console.log(display);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (display) {
      document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
    }
  }, [display, handleClick]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (show) {
      setDisplay(show);
    } else {
      setDisplay(false);
    }
  }, [show]);

  return <div>{display && <p>Hi</p>}</div>;
};
```

**Issues:**

- The component is **unable to clear** the event listener because a **new reference** of the function `handleClick()` is made every time `Example` renders.
- Every time `handleClick()` is called, it logs `display` as **true**.
- After **7-8 mouse clicks**, the log **count** in console reaches to **7-8K**.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks :)

Comment: looks like you already know the problem. To avoid lose reference to the actual handler, I think you can probably pass the handler via arguments, or use a class component such that the handler will not be created every time the render executes, or create the handler out of the method somewhere...

Comment: @Surely I am not really using class component, so that can't be solution as such. Other thing, I didn’t understand about passing the handler via arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to clean up in a useEffect, return a function in the effect. That function will be called every time the effect re-runs and when the component unmounts.

The reason why this will allow for the event listener to be properly removed is because the useEffect creates a closure over the current version of the `handleClick` function. Which allows the clean-up function to have the same reference so it can be properly cleaned up. It didn't work in the original because every time the useEffect re-ran, a new version of the `handleClick` was closed over and then the clean-up was tried with the new version.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!display) {
    return;
  }

  document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

  return () => document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
}, [display, handleClick]);
```

You can further make the effect occur less often by using a ref to the `handleClick`function instead.

For instance at it's most basic. Though you can easily abstract some of the reference and extra use-effect to a separate hook.

```
const handleClickRef = useRef(handleClick);

useEffect(()=>{
  handleClickRef.current = handleClick;
},[handleClick])

useEffect(() => {
  if (!display) {
    return;
  }
  const funct = (evt)=>handleClickRef.current(evt);
  document.addEventListener('click',funct);

  return () => document.removeEventListener('click', funct);
}, [display]);
```

Comment: My component is never un-mounting so, that's not a feasible solution.

Comment: As mentioned, it also takes care of the cleanup whenever the effect re-runs, so it will properly take care of the cleanup of the event listener.